# angularjs map latitude and longitude

Tags: google-maps, latitude-longitude, angularjs-1.6

I am using angularjs 1.x and want an api that provide me the following things

**1)I should be able to search the location (auto populate functionality required)**

**2)can select the location by drag and drop**

**3)Get the latitude and longitude**

which api can satisfy these 3 requirement ? please update !

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the framework, you can use the Google Maps Javascript API for those. I'll just link you to the docs. Just load the Javascript library whichever AngularJS 1.xx way you want and you can call its services in your controller.

1. [Search location with autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete)
2. [Add markers to the map + get coordinates](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers) (markers are draggable and you get get its coordinates after you add a marker)
3. [Get coordinates given free text](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding)

P.S.

I'm sure you're aware that your question is very general which will make it difficult for others to help you. If you need more specific answers, post your attempted code.